# Convert string to date and get Day

Tags: javascript, node.js, date-format, string-to-datetime

How to convert string Date to Date?

I have a string "20210712" in the format yyyymmdd how to convert it into date...And how to get the day of It.

Comment: Do you want the day of month or the day of week? How have you tried to get it? Can you show us your effort?

Comment: What does this have to do with nodejs? Are you sure you want a solution in Java rather than in JavaScript?

Comment: @deHaar where is nodejs mentioned?

Comment: @Reporter in the tags

Comment: @deHaar it's better to have a solution in javascript.

Comment: @SanjeevAV Then please use the corresponding tags, you have not tagged your question JavaScript, but Java. That won't increase your chances to get a solution in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to split the date string into its components. We'll use the + shorthand to convert each component into a number, then create a new Date object from it, using the Date [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#syntax) `new Date(year, monthIndex, day)`.

NB: In JavaScript we pass the *monthIndex* to the Date rather than the month number, so July is represented as monthIndex = 6;

To get the day of the month from your date, you'll need [Date.getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate).

To get the day of the week from your date, you'll need [Date.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), this will return 0 - 6 (Sunday (0) -> Saturday (6))

To get the day of the week as a string from your date, you can use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat), this will return 'Monday' -> 'Sunday'.

```js
const timestamp = "20210712";
const year = +timestamp.substr(0,4);
const monthIndex = +timestamp.substr(4,2) - 1;
const day = +timestamp.substr(6,2);

console.log("Timestamp:", timestamp)
console.log("Date components:", JSON.stringify({ year, monthIndex, day }))

const date = new Date(year ,monthIndex, day);
console.log('Date:', date.toDateString());
console.log('Day of Month:', date.getDate());

// Sunday - Saturday : 0 - 6
console.log('Day of Week (0-6):', date.getDay());
console.log('Day of Week (string):', new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { weekday: 'long'}).format(date))
```

Comment: I am new to javascript, I am not able to run this code...How to run it in web to get the output.

Comment: I would suggest using something like https://jsfiddle.net/ to test simple functions like this. You can paste any code you wish to test into the JavaScript window. I've created a fiddle you can test: https://jsfiddle.net/su3baj0n/. NB: Press F12 before running so you can see the console output. You could also create a node.js script. Install node.js, then create your script, say script.js and in your command window: node script.js.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with use of DateTimeFormatter and LocalDate:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20210712", formatter);
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(date.getDayOfWeek());
System.out.println(date.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(date.getDayOfYear());
```

Output:

```
2021-07-12
MONDAY
12
193
```

Comment: I am new to JavaScript!. Tried pasting your code inside the script, it shows some errors. Not running, What should I do to run it without any error

Comment: Java is different from JavaScript. The solution I proposed is in Java, as the original tag of your question, it won't work in JavaScript.